# Creating a delay for winning or loosing picture

Tags: python, time, timer, pygame, wait

In my code I am trying to create a game and when you get a certain amount of points you will get either a winning or loosing sign. but the issue i am having is that the loosing or winning screen is not showing for enough time.

If I try to use a function like pygame.time.wait() or pygame.time.wait() either of these just stop the game on the frame where the final bullet either makes you win ore loose but unfortunately only shows the you loose or the you in screen for about one hundredth of a second which is not what i want.

```
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.freetype
import random
import time


pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("this game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.

bomb =pygame.font.get_fonts()

#print(bomb)

class Background:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/space.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))



class Loosing:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/eye.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class Winning:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/lightspeed.jpeg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))



class Annoy:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/Ocram_animated_2.gif").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y


    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))




class Player_one:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/ezgif.com-crop.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))



class Player_two:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/Giantmechanicalcrab2 - Copy.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (300, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))



class Bullet_player_one(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/giphy.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    def __init__(self, owner, start_x, start_y, speed_x):
        self.owner = owner
        self.xpos = start_x
        self.ypos = start_y
        self.speed_x = speed_x
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos


        if self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left > screen.get_width():
            self.kill()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


class Bullet_player_two(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/MajesticLavishBackswimmer-size_restricted.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    picture = pygame.transform.rotate(picture, 180)
    def __init__(self, owner, start_x, start_y, speed_x):
        self.owner = owner
        self.xpos = start_x
        self.ypos = start_y
        self.speed_x = speed_x
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
        if self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left > screen.get_width():
            self.kill()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)







class Bullet_right(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/big_boy.png").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    def __init__(self, owner, start_x, start_y, speed_x):
        self.owner = owner
        self.xpos = start_x
        self.ypos = start_y
        self.speed_x = speed_x
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
        if self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left > screen.get_width():
            self.kill()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)









class Bullet_left(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/blinking_doge_by_euamodeus-d7vjq7m.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    def __init__(self, owner, start_x, start_y, speed_x):
        self.owner = owner
        self.xpos = start_x
        self.ypos = start_y
        self.speed_x = speed_x
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos

    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.rect.x = self.xpos
        self.rect.y = self.ypos
        if self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left > screen.get_width():
            self.kill()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


#class Text:
#    def __init__(self, x, y, texty, score):
#        self.ypos = y
#        self.xpos = x
#        self.text = texty
#        self.score = score
#
#    def update(self):
#        
#
#    def draw(self):
#        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))




player_one = Player_one(0, 500)
player_two = Player_two(1000, 0)
skull = Annoy(520, -100)
cliff = Background(0, 0)
player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_two_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
right_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
left_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_one_bullet = None
player_two_bullet = None
left = None
right = None
count = 100
wait = 100
locked = True
lockered = True
player_one_score = 0
player_two_score = 0
loaded = True
ready = True
lose = Loosing(0, 0)
win = Winning(0, 0)
word = ""
difficulty = input("easy, medium or hard")
locked = False
ping = False
done = False
diff = []
on_ground = False
if difficulty != "easy" and difficulty != "medium" and difficulty != "hard":
    while difficulty != "easy" and difficulty != "medium" and difficulty != "hard":
        difficulty = input("easy, medium or hard")

while True:


    basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('impact', 48)
    text = basicfont.render(' player one Score:' + str(player_one_score), True, (255, 125, 0), (0, 0, 0))
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery



    basicfont_two = pygame.font.SysFont('impact', 48)
    text_two = basicfont.render('player two Score:' + str(player_two_score) , True, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
    textrect = text.get_rect()
    textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery




    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player_one.speed_y = -5

            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player_one.speed_y = 5

            #elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                #player_two.speed_y = -5

            #elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                #player_two.speed_y = 5

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if len(player_one_bullet_list) == 0:
                    player_one_bullet = Bullet_player_one(player_one, player_one.xpos, player_one.ypos, 20)
                    player_one_bullet_list.add(player_one_bullet)
                    pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Big_Explosion_Cut_Off.wav"))






            #elif event.key == pygame.K_KP0:










        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # Stop moving when the keys are released.
            if event.key == pygame.K_s and player_one.speed_y > 0:
                player_one.speed_y = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w and player_one.speed_y < 0:
                player_one.speed_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player_two.speed_y > 0:
                player_two.speed_y = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and player_two.speed_y < 0:
                player_two.speed_y = 0


    if difficulty == "easy":
        choice = random.randint(1, 10)
        choosen = random.randint(1, 10)
        if choice == 2 and choosen == 4 or choice == 4 and choosen == 2:
            if len(player_two_bullet_list) == 0:
                player_two_bullet = Bullet_player_two(player_two, player_two.xpos, player_two.ypos, -20)
                player_two_bullet_list.add(player_two_bullet)
                pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Dumpster_Rattle.wav"))

    elif difficulty == "medium":
        choice = random.randint(1, 10)
        if choice == 2 or choice == 4 or choice == 6 or choice == 8 or choice == 10:
            if len(player_two_bullet_list) == 0:
                player_two_bullet = Bullet_player_two(player_two, player_two.xpos, player_two.ypos, -20)
                player_two_bullet_list.add(player_two_bullet)
                pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Dumpster_Rattle.wav"))


    else:
        choice = random.randint(1, 10)
        if choice == 2 or choice == 4 or choice == 6 or choice == 8 or choice == 10 or choice == 5 or choice == 7 or choice == 9 or choice == 1:
            if len(player_two_bullet_list) == 0:
                player_two_bullet = Bullet_player_two(player_two, player_two.xpos, player_two.ypos, -20)
                player_two_bullet_list.add(player_two_bullet)
                pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/dumper.wav"))





    if difficulty == "easy":
        chooso = random.randint(1, 10)
        if chooso == 9 or chooso == 4:
            if on_ground == False:
                choosing = random.randint(1, 10)
                if choosing == 3:
                    skull.speed_y = 10
                    if skull.ypos == 520:
                            on_ground = True
            else:
                skull.speed_y = -10
                if skull.ypos == -100:
                    on_ground = False

        else:
            skull.speed_y = 0

        choosa = random.randint(1, 10)
        locking = random.randint(1, 10)
        if choosa == 3 and locking == 7 and len(right_list) == 0:
            right = Bullet_right(skull, skull.xpos, skull.ypos, -20) #should be left
            right_list.add(right)

        elif choosa == 4 and locking == 8 and len(left_list) == 0:
            left = Bullet_left(skull, skull.xpos, skull.ypos, 20) #should be right
            left_list.add(left)




    if player_one.ypos == 520:
        player_one.speed_y = -5

    if player_one.ypos == 0:
        player_one.speed_y = +5

    if player_two.ypos == 520:
        player_two.speed_y = -5

    if player_two.ypos == 0:
        player_two.speed_y = +5


#    if player_one_bullet.xpos == 520:
#        player_one_bullet.kill()

    player_one.update()
    player_two.update()
    skull.update()
    cliff.draw()
    player_one.draw()
    player_two.draw()
    skull.draw()
    screen.blit(text, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_two, (700, 0))

    player_one_bullet_list.update()
    player_two_bullet_list.update()
    left_list.update()
    right_list.update()

    for player_one_bullet in player_one_bullet_list:
        player_one_bullet.draw()

    for player_two_bullet in player_two_bullet_list:
        player_two_bullet.draw()

    for left in left_list:
        left.draw()

    for right in right_list:
        right.draw()

    for bullet in player_one_bullet_list:
        if bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
            player_one_bullet.kill()
            player_one_score +=1
            pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Beep_Short.wav"))


            #pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/sounds/hammond.wav")
            #pygame.mixer.music.play(3)


    for bullet in player_two_bullet_list:
        if bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):
            player_two_bullet.kill()
            player_two_score +=1
            pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/sounds/Emergency_Siren_Short_Burst.wav"))

#        if bullet.is_collided_with(skull):
#            player_two_bullet.kill()
#            if player_two_score == 0:
#                player_two_score = 0
#            elif player_two_score > 0:
#                player_two_score = player_two_score-1
#        elif bullet.is_collided_with(player_one_bullet):
#            player_one_bullet.kill()
#            player_two_bullet.kill()
            #pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/sounds/clarkson.wav")
            #pygame.mixer.music.play(3)


    for right in right_list:
        if right.is_collided_with(player_one):
            right.kill()
            if player_one_score == 0:
                player_one_score = 0
            else:
                player_one_score += -1

    for left in left_list:
        if left.is_collided_with(player_two):
            left.kill()
            if player_two_score == 0:
                player_two_score = 0
            else:
                player_two_score += -1




    if player_one_score == 100:
        win.draw()
        basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('sylfaen', 120)
        texto = basicfont.render('You Win!', True, (0, 255, 0)) #(0, 0, 0))
        textrecto = text.get_rect()
        textrecto.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
        textrecto.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
        screen.blit(texto, (400, 360))
        clock.tick(1)
        player_one_score = 0
        player_two_score = 0

    elif player_two_score == 100:
        lose.draw()
        basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont('chiller', 120)
        texte = basicfont.render('You Lose!', True, (255, 0, 0)) #(0, 0, 0))
        textrecte = text.get_rect()
        textrecte.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
        textrecte.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
        screen.blit(texte, (400, 360))
        clock.tick(1)
        player_one_score = 0
        player_two_score = 0







    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

so far what outputs i get are thing like the screen freezes on the final attack waits and then shows the code and when shows the you win or loose sign only for about 1\100th of a second which is not enough and also when I put it below most of the code as well it does the exact thing

Answer (score 0):

In the last two if statements, you reset the scores to 0.

```
player_one_score = 0
player_two_score = 0
```

This causes the if statements to not be executed in the next loop, so the "You win"/"You lose" sign is not drawn in the next loop. Maybe you can make a button to restart the game, which when clicked, resets the scores to 0 and restart the game.